# Invert a string: Recursion vs iteration in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration, big-o

one month ago I've been interviewed by some google PTO members.
One of the questions was: 
**Invert a string recursively in js and explain the running time by big O notation**

this was my solution:

```
function invert(s){
    return (s.length > 1) ? s.charAt(s.length-1)+invert(s.substring(0,s.length-1)) : s;
}
```

Pretty simple, I think.

And, about the big-o notation, I quickly answered O(n) as the running time depends linearly on the input. - Silence - and then, he asked me, what are the differences in terms of running time if you implement it by iteration?

I replied that sometimes the compiler "translate" the recursion into iteration (some programming language course memories) so there are no differences about iteration and recursion in this case. Btw since I had no feedback about this particular question, and the interviewer didn't answer "ok" or "nope", I'd like to know if you maybe agree with me or if you can explain me whether there could be differences about the 2 kind of implementations.

Thanks a lot and Regards!

Comment: I am not sure, but there could be a call stack generation overhead in the recursion, that wouldn't be a in a loop.

Comment: Btw i'd have stored s.length instead of accessing it 3 times, but maybe there was no need for optimization... (sorry i always optimize prematurely, it's one of my many faults)

Comment: @Martin: call stack generation should be a *very* tiny overhead. In any case, the code here recurses n times, it has the same computational complexity as a loop that iterates n times.

Comment: @Martin @Juliet: thanks, so.. do you think (apart from the length that could be stored) that computational complexity doesn't change from recursion to iteration?

Comment: I am not a compiler/interpreter expert by a long shot, so all i can give you is some musings based on my experience with coding javascript, which i have done since 1997 (serverside, netscape faststrack server, don't ask ;). Iteration is always faster than recursion if you know the amount of iterations to go through from the start. I would never have implemented string inversion by recursion myself in a project that actually needed to go into production. That said, i find it to be an elegant solution :)

Comment: Yeah, I think so..but he asked me about recursion so I had to do that way :D ..however, I'm a lil confused about the time complexity that is not O(n).. I'd have to review my Cormen book :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks O(*n*²) to me. The call to `substring` is most likely O(*n*) — a typical implementation will allocate space for a new string and then copy the substring across. [But see comments.] The string concatenation `+` will probably also be O(*n*). It may even be the case that `length` is O(*n*) but I think this is fairly unlikely.

---

You brought up the idea that a compiler can transform recursion into iteration. This is true, but it's rarely implemented outside of functional languages and Scheme; and typically the only transformation that gets applied is *tail recursion elimination*. In your code, the recursion is not in *tail position*: after the recursive call to `invert` you've still got to compute the `+`. So tail recursion elimination does not apply to your code.

That means that an iterative version of `invert` would have to be implemented in a different way. It might have the same or different complexity, we can't say until we've seen it.

Comment: Really? I don't know javascript very well, but in most languages I do know, substring is O(1), sharing the storage of the original string (either because strings are immutable or substrings are implemented using copy-on-write).

Comment: The question didn't say which JavaScript implementation was being used, hence my caveats. (I once implemented JavaScript and my `substring` was O(n), so it's true of at least one JS implementation!) But even if you're right about `substring`, it seems likely that the `+` is O(n).

Comment: @sepp2k: The problem with O(1) substringing is that it really screws up garbage collection. If I allocate a multi-megabyte string, pull 5 characters out of the middle, and then let the original string go out of scope, it's still not eligible for collection because the tiny substring is still floating around.

Comment: @Gareth: Yes, `+` will almost certainly be O(n), that's true.

Comment: @sepp2k: Prompted by your comment, I did a bit of research, and as far as I can tell, the [`substring` implementation in V8](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/v8/src/heap.cc&q=substring&exact_package=chromium&d=3) allocates and copies as I described.

Comment: @Gareth: Interesting. Good to know.

Comment: @sepp2k @Gareth: thanks a lot for your replies! So I think that "silence" was about my O(n) reply :) ..I can't understand, why is the + O(n)? Also, what about recursion vs iteration, should it be the same?

Comment: `+` is O(n) because it (most likely) allocates space for the concatenation and then copies its argument strings across.

Comment: Thank you very much Gareth :) ..now I understand everything about the interviewer "silence" :)

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, to use tail recursion which allows the compiler to implement your recursion as a loop, you cannot have state left on the stack. To work around this you can pass the "state" as an additional parameter to your function:

```
function invert(sofar, s)
{
    return (s.length > 0) ? invert(s.charAt(s.length-1)+sofar, s.substring(0,s.length-1)) :  sofar;
}
```

Comment: I don't think most (if any) JavaScript engines perform Tail Call Optimization

Comment: That is true, I only mentioned it since the OP brought up the optimization possibilities in his question

Comment: You're right @BrokenGlass. The example should optimize everything 'optimizable' :D ..I think he asked me about this kind of stuff just to know if I were able to do anything about the opt.. btw in this case do you think the recursion is not "converted" into iteration?

Comment: In the example you gave it cannot be optimized, even theoretically since you `return xxx + invert(yyy)` so the compiler has to keep `xxx` on the stack, recursively compute `invert(yyy)` then unwind the stack and do the addition. That's why it's better to do a `return invert(yyy, xxx)` so there is no state left on the stack. This is called a tail recursion that can be optimized to a loop (but won't for Javascript)